# Unable to add css property to <td> element by clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build a pixel marker webpage for a project. It is almost completed. I am facing a couple of problems:

1. Unable to fill in the color, when a `<td>` tag is clicked.
2. The `wells` that contain the color options and the input value to the grid, over flow the vertical line when I resize the browser. I need the width tag here because I want it to fill 100% of the column size it is located in. I had to use a hard coded value here because if I use 100% as the width value, the wells fill the entire width of the window when the browser is resized.

PLease refer to the output here: https://codepen.io/gauravthantry/pen/LdbxZg.

Note:- I just got a notification saying that this question is a duplicate of [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

The question asked in the above post is the answer to my question.

Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid-input").click(function() {
        $(".drawing-area").empty();

        var rows = $("#row").val();
        var cols = $("#col").val();
        if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {
            if (rows < 8 || cols < 8) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
                    var rowClassName = 'row' + i;
                    var tr = $('<tr>').addClass(rowClassName);
                    tr.appendTo('.drawing-area'); //Adding dynamic class names whenever a new table row is created

                    for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                        var colClassName = 'col' + j;
                        $('<td width="30px" height="30px" style="border: 1px solid #000; "></a></td>').addClass(colClassName).appendTo(tr);
                    }
                    $('.drawing-area').append('</tr>');

                }
                $('.drawing-area').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');



            } else if ((rows >= 8 && rows <= 20) && (cols >= 8 && cols <= 50)) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
                    var rowClassName = 'row' + i;
                    var tr = $('<tr>').addClass(rowClassName);
                    tr.appendTo('.drawing-area'); //Adding dynamic class names whenever a new table row is created

                    for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                        var colClassName = 'col' + j;
                        $('<td width="20px" height="20px" style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center;"></a></td>').addClass(colClassName).appendTo(tr);
                    }

                }
                $('.drawing-area').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');


            } else if (rows > 20 || cols > 50) {
                alert('Bamm!!! Your input will flood the browser\'s belly');
            }
        } else {
            alert("You haven't provided the grid size!");
        }
    });
    $('td').click(function() {
        var color = $("input[name='color']:checked").val();
  concole.log(color);
        if (color === 'blue') {
            if ($(this).hasClass('colorFill-Blue'))
                $(this).removeClass('colorFill-Blue');
            else
                $(this).addClass('colorFill-Blue');

        } else if (color === 'green') {
            if ($(this).hasClass('colorFill-Green'))
                $(this).removeClass('colorFill-Green');
            else
                $(this).addClass('colorFill-Green');
            alert("green is selected");
        } else {
            if ($(this).hasClass('colorFill-Yellow'))
                $(this).removeClass('colorFill-Yellow');
            else
                $(this).addClass('colorFill-Yellow');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.page-position{
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/03/50/f8035042eda4eaeac4013e4f79ed85b2.jpg");
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}

.content-position{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); 
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 96%;
 position: absolute;
}

.heading{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.fa1{
    color: blue;
}
.fa2{
    color: yellow;
}
.fa3{
    color: green;
}

.vertical-line{
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    height: 478px;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.color-option-container{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
 
}



.grid-size-container{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
 width: 300px;
    
 
}

.text-line{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: transparent;
}

.rows{
    float: left;
}

.cols{
    float: center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.drawing-area{
    text-align: center;
 visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-size{
 text-align: center;
width: 60px;
}

.colorFill-Blue{
 background-color: blue;
}
.colorFill-Green{
 background-color: green;
}

.colorFill-Yellow{
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>PIXEL ART MAKER</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="page-position">
    <!-- Content starts here -->
    <section class="content-position container-fluid">
        <section class="heading">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> DRAW THE PIXELS</h1>
        </section>
        <hr>
        <section>
            <section class="row-fluid">
                <section class="col-md-3">
                    <section class="well well-lg color-option-container">
                        <form class="color-select">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue" checked><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i>&nbsp; BLUE
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa2"></i> &nbsp;YELLOW
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa3"></i> &nbsp;GREEN
                        </form>
                    </section>
                    <br>
                    <section class="well well-lg grid-size-container">

                        <input type="text" class="text-line rows" id="row" placeholder="Rows">

                        <input type="text" class="text-line cols" id="col" placeholder="Cols">
                        <br/>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn-size btn btn-block btn-primary" id="grid-input"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                    </section>

                </section>
                <section class="col-md-1 vertical-line"></section>
                <section class="col-md-7">
                    <table class="drawing-area">

                    </table>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your elements are dynamically created. You need to target an element available on page load and make use of event delegation.

Comment: @ObsidianAge. Thank you for your prompt reply. The elements have already been loaded. I am trying to access the <td> tags once all the elements have been created. Could you please give me an example of how could I use event delegation here? Because in a grid, the user can select any of the <td> tags. And the only way I can think of to target that element is by using `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Because your elements are dynamically created, you need to attach the click event handler to an element that is available on page load, and make use of **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**. Instead of `$('td').click()`, you're looking for `$('body').on("click", "td", function() {} )`.

Also note that in addition to this, your `concole.log` should be **[`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)**.

I've corrected this in the following example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid-input").click(function() {
    $(".drawing-area").empty();

    var rows = $("#row").val();
    var cols = $("#col").val();
    if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {
      if (rows < 8 || cols < 8) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
          var rowClassName = 'row' + i;
          var tr = $('<tr>').addClass(rowClassName);
          tr.appendTo('.drawing-area'); //Adding dynamic class names whenever a new table row is created

          for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            var colClassName = 'col' + j;
            $('<td width="30px" height="30px" style="border: 1px solid #000; "></a></td>').addClass(colClassName).appendTo(tr);
          }
          $('.drawing-area').append('</tr>');

        }
        $('.drawing-area').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');



      } else if ((rows >= 8 && rows <= 20) && (cols >= 8 && cols <= 50)) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
          var rowClassName = 'row' + i;
          var tr = $('<tr>').addClass(rowClassName);
          tr.appendTo('.drawing-area'); //Adding dynamic class names whenever a new table row is created

          for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            var colClassName = 'col' + j;
            $('<td width="20px" height="20px" style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center;"></a></td>').addClass(colClassName).appendTo(tr);
          }

        }
        $('.drawing-area').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('slow');


      } else if (rows > 20 || cols > 50) {
        alert('Bamm!!! Your input will flood the browser\'s belly');
      }
    } else {
      alert("You haven't provided the grid size!");
    }
  });
  $('body').on("click", "td", function() {
    var color = $("input[name='color']:checked").val();
    console.log(color);
    if (color === 'blue') {
      if ($(this).hasClass('colorFill-Blue'))
        $(this).removeClass('colorFill-Blue');
      else
        $(this).addClass('colorFill-Blue');

    } else if (color === 'green') {
      if ($(this).hasClass('colorFill-Green'))
        $(this).removeClass('colorFill-Green');
      else
        $(this).addClass('colorFill-Green');
      alert("green is selected");
    } else {
      if ($(this).hasClass('colorFill-Yellow'))
        $(this).removeClass('colorFill-Yellow');
      else
        $(this).addClass('colorFill-Yellow');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.page-position {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/03/50/f8035042eda4eaeac4013e4f79ed85b2.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-position {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  height: 600px;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.fa1 {
  color: blue;
}

.fa2 {
  color: yellow;
}

.fa3 {
  color: green;
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  height: 478px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.color-option-container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.grid-size-container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  width: 300px;
}

.text-line {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}

.rows {
  float: left;
}

.cols {
  float: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.drawing-area {
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-size {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

.colorFill-Blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.colorFill-Green {
  background-color: green;
}

.colorFill-Yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>PIXEL ART MAKER</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="page-position">
  <!-- Content starts here -->
  <section class="content-position container-fluid">
    <section class="heading">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> DRAW THE PIXELS</h1>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section>
      <section class="row-fluid">
        <section class="col-md-3">
          <section class="well well-lg color-option-container">
            <form class="color-select">
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue" checked><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i>&nbsp; BLUE
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa2"></i> &nbsp;YELLOW
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa3"></i> &nbsp;GREEN
            </form>
          </section>
          <br>
          <section class="well well-lg grid-size-container">

            <input type="text" class="text-line rows" id="row" placeholder="Rows">

            <input type="text" class="text-line cols" id="col" placeholder="Cols">
            <br/>

            <button type="submit" class="btn-size btn btn-block btn-primary" id="grid-input"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

          </section>

        </section>
        <section class="col-md-1 vertical-line"></section>
        <section class="col-md-7">
          <table class="drawing-area">

          </table>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Heh almost the same answer ;) good job

Answer (score 0):

#### [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRbWJP)

Two things:

1. Your `td` elements are dynamically created, but your code uses `$("td").click(…)` which only binds to the TD elements at the time that is called.  Instead of binding an event on the existing TDs, a simpler and more efficient fix is to bind the event to a more static ancestor.  The `table` element is a static ancestor, so changing your click definition to `$('table').on('click','td',function(){...})` will ensure that the dynamic TDs are included.
    
   This means when you click anywhere in the table, the function will see if the target was a `td` and if so it will call the included function.
2. You had an error in the code, where what should have been `console` was  spelled `concole`.

I've fixed both of these below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#grid-input").click(function() {
    $(".drawing-area").empty();

    var rows = $("#row").val();
    var cols = $("#col").val();
    if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {
      if (rows < 8 || cols < 8) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
          var rowClassName = "row" + i;
          var tr = $("<tr>").addClass(rowClassName);
          tr.appendTo(".drawing-area"); //Adding dynamic class names whenever a new table row is created

          for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            var colClassName = "col" + j;
            $(
                '<td width="30px" height="30px" style="border: 1px solid #000; "></a></td>'
              )
              .addClass(colClassName)
              .appendTo(tr);
          }
          $(".drawing-area").append("</tr>");
        }
        $(".drawing-area")
          .css("visibility", "visible")
          .hide()
          .fadeIn("slow");
      } else if (rows >= 8 && rows <= 20 && (cols >= 8 && cols <= 50)) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
          var rowClassName = "row" + i;
          var tr = $("<tr>").addClass(rowClassName);
          tr.appendTo(".drawing-area"); //Adding dynamic class names whenever a new table row is created

          for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            var colClassName = "col" + j;
            $(
                '<td width="20px" height="20px" style="border: 1px solid #000; text-align: center;"></a></td>'
              )
              .addClass(colClassName)
              .appendTo(tr);
          }
        }
        $(".drawing-area")
          .css("visibility", "visible")
          .hide()
          .fadeIn("slow");
      } else if (rows > 20 || cols > 50) {
        alert("Bamm!!! Your input will flood the browser's belly");
      }
    } else {
      alert("You haven't provided the grid size!");
    }
  });
  $("table").on('click', 'td', function() {
    var color = $("input[name='color']:checked").val();
    console.log(color);
    if (color === "blue") {
      if ($(this).hasClass("colorFill-Blue"))
        $(this).removeClass("colorFill-Blue");
      else $(this).addClass("colorFill-Blue");
    } else if (color === "green") {
      if ($(this).hasClass("colorFill-Green"))
        $(this).removeClass("colorFill-Green");
      else $(this).addClass("colorFill-Green");
      alert("green is selected");
    } else {
      if ($(this).hasClass("colorFill-Yellow"))
        $(this).removeClass("colorFill-Yellow");
      else $(this).addClass("colorFill-Yellow");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.page-position {
  background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f8/03/50/f8035042eda4eaeac4013e4f79ed85b2.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-position {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  height: 600px;
  width: 96%;
  position: absolute;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.fa1 {
  color: blue;
}

.fa2 {
  color: yellow;
}

.fa3 {
  color: green;
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  height: 478px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.color-option-container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.grid-size-container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  width: 300px;
}

.text-line {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: transparent;
}

.rows {
  float: left;
}

.cols {
  float: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.drawing-area {
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.btn-size {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
}

.colorFill-Blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.colorFill-Green {
  background-color: green;
}

.colorFill-Yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>PIXEL ART MAKER</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="page-position">
  <!-- Content starts here -->
  <section class="content-position container-fluid">
    <section class="heading">
      <h1><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i> DRAW THE PIXELS</h1>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <section>
      <section class="row-fluid">
        <section class="col-md-3">
          <section class="well well-lg color-option-container">
            <form class="color-select">
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" id="blue" checked><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa1"></i>&nbsp; BLUE
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="yellow" id="yellow"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa2"></i> &nbsp;YELLOW
              <br>
              <input type="radio" name="color" value="green" id="green"><i class="fa fa-fire-extinguisher fa3"></i> &nbsp;GREEN
            </form>
          </section>
          <br>
          <section class="well well-lg grid-size-container">

            <input type="text" class="text-line rows" id="row" placeholder="Rows">

            <input type="text" class="text-line cols" id="col" placeholder="Cols">
            <br/>

            <button type="submit" class="btn-size btn btn-block btn-primary" id="grid-input"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

          </section>

        </section>
        <section class="col-md-1 vertical-line"></section>
        <section class="col-md-7">
          <table class="drawing-area">

          </table>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```